# Not sure if jquery working on <li> items because of firebug

Tags: jquery, html, css

Would someone mind checking my site in Firebug? It looks like the jquery hide/show is working but I don't know why it is not highlighting as if it were showing in firebug. I'm looking at mousing over the "design" block. The reason I want it to show up (not in light grey, indicating that it might not really being working) is that I want to be able to css position the text in the link.

http://freespiriteurodesign.com.b1.bloomsite.net/

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Firebug shows no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found nothing but you may add this code snippet to avoid this error "event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
(function(){
    // remove layerX and layerY
    var all = $.event.props,
        len = all.length,
        res = [];
    while (len--) {
      var el = all[len];
      if (el != 'layerX' && el != 'layerY') res.push(el);
    }
    $.event.props = res;
}());
```

});

Or you may upgrade your jquery to the newer version.